# Почему у меня не срабатывает catch в Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, try-catch

Пытаюсь вывести ошибку на экран в модальное окно, но модальное окно срабатывает только когда **error !== null**, и после **try**, если что-то пошло не так, должна сработать **catch**, но по какой-то причине она просто не срабатывает, браузер ее пропускает словно ее вообще не существует, в итоге переменная **error** остается **null** как изначально, и ошибка не выводится в модальном окне, но в самой консоле видно что ошибка есть, и при логировании в **actions.js** она выводится в консоль, но в компоненте как я сказал выше catch пропускается.

**VUEX Store console.warn срабатывает и показывает что ошибка есть => actions.js**

```
async auth(context, payload){
let url = 'http://linktofirebase'
    const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: payload.email,
            password: payload.password,
            returnSecureToken: true,
          }),
        });

    const responseData = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      const error = new Error(
        responseData.message || "Failed to authenticate. Check your login data."
      );
      console.warn("Response isnt ok: " + error);
      throw error;
    }
}
```

**Component в которую не передается ошибка => UserAuth.vue**

```
 async authorization(){    
    try {
            if (this.mode === "login") {
              console.log("Login");
              await this.$store.dispatch("login", actionPayload);
            } else {
              console.log("Signup");
              await this.$store.dispatch("signup", actionPayload);
            }
            // Try срабатывает и дальше он просто проходит мимо catch, даже если я вызвал ошибку.
          } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error");
            this.error = error.message || "Failed to authenticate, try later.";
          }
          console.log(this.error);
        }
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, оказывается я забыл добавить "return" к двум функция выше

```
    login(context, payload) {
    return context.dispatch("auth", {
      ...payload,
      mode: "login",
    });
  },
  signup(context, payload) {
    return context.dispatch("auth", {
      ...payload,
      mode: "signup",
    });
  },
```

И по этой причине я не получал ошибку в компонент.